# What's the most efficient way of keeping water hot?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, heat-conduction

Given a house with a large hot water tank of several cubic meters that is warmed by two wood burning boilers, I'm trying to figure out what is the best strategy to keep the water hot using the least amount of wood.

Is it better to keep the average tank temperature at 40-60 degrees, or would it be best to target a range of 60-80 degrees Celsius?

The water egress is mostly for showers and hand wash, as well as a radiator heating system that gets it's temperature from the hot water in the tank.

This is for a system in a cold country, with very cold winters.

My hypothesis is that given water's thermal capacity, it's better to store the water hotter rather than cooler, as it takes less wood to keep it hot once it's hot, rather than constantly adding wood to maintain a mid-level temperature.

Any thoughts on the physics behind this scenario?

Comment: Important to note: There is a system which mixes in cold water to allow a max output of 60 degrees to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

In general there are three heat transfer mechanisms:

1. Conduction
2. Convection
3. Radiation

###### 1. Conduction  $ \quad  \Delta Q \propto \Delta T$

The heat flux density is proportional to the gradient of the temperature between the outisde and the inside. Assuming a one dimensional problem, that means the bigger the temperature difference $\Delta T$ between the water in the tank and the outside the more heat $\Delta Q$  will get transferred.

###### 2. Convection: not relevant

With the assumption that the tank is closed this mechanism becomes irrelevant.

###### 3. Radiation $\quad \Delta Q \propto T^4$

According to the Stefan-Boltzmann Law the power which is emitted by a black body is proportional to T to the power of 4. So the radiation emitted by the hot water and/or the surface of the tank increases dramatically if the temperature of the hot object increases.

*Conclusion:*

Lower temperature in the tank leads to lower losses and thus to less wood burned.